# InfoPath 2010 Property Promotion creates columns in SharePoint 2010, but form data isn't saved to them

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010, infopath-forms-services

I have an InfoPath 2010 form published to a SharePoint 2010 form library.  When the form is filled out and submitted, the form gets saved, but the field data does not populate the columns that were created by InfoPath using property promotion.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

Check for duplicates - Open the list settings page and check the column internal names by clicking "edit" and then check the name in the addressbar of your browser.